# script to automatically update blockips table in nftable

Tags: shell, nftables

I want to write a sh script in order to update my nftable `badips`:

```
table inet my_table {
        set badips {
                type ipv4_addr
                flags interval
                elements = { 0.0.0.0/8, 1.2.177.195, ... }

        chain my_input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                iifname "lo" accept comment "Accept anything from lo interface"
                ct state vmap { invalid : drop, established : accept, related : accept }
                tcp dport { 80, 8443 } ct state new limit rate 10/second accept comment "[nftables] Allow HTTP/HTTPS traffic but limit them to 10 new connections per second"
                ip saddr @badips drop comment "[nftables] Block ban IP"
                log prefix "[nftables log] " flags all
        }
}
```

I want to download several [firehol IP lists](https://iplists.firehol.org/) after some time and add to my badips:

```
nft add element inet my_table badips { <IP> }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to update the section `0.0.0.0/8, 1.2.177.195, ...`, where the `...` is an ever growing list of IPs? Recommend that you "build" your config file from a shell HERE file and use `{ $( sed '!$s/.*/&,/' IPlistFile.txt | tr -d \013 ) }` for that line (`0.0.0.0/8, 1.2.177.195, ...`). Put each IP on line by itself and edit that file, rather than try to inline edit your cfg file. Use your shell script to "regenerate" the config file each time you need it. ...

Comment: There are probably other patterns you can use that would achieve the same idea. use an `IPListFile.txt` and convert it into `0.0.0.0/8, 1.2.177.195, ...`. G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner should work:

```
grep -v "^#" IPlist.txt | while read addr ; \
do nft add element inet my_table badips { ${addr} } ; done
```

Replace IPlist.txt with the name of the list you downloaded.

If the list contains subnets you may need to remove '/32' from ipv4 ranges because nftables can't handle it (checked on v1.0.2 and older):

```
grep -v "^#" IPlist.txt | while read addr ; \
do grep -qs ':' <<<"${addr}" || addr=$(sed 's/\/32$//' <<<"${addr}") ; \
nft add element inet my_table badips { ${addr} } ; done
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I read *at once* the file and separate contents by commas and take advance that `nft add` could invoke by commas (eg. `nft add .... {1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, ...}`?

Comment: Yes, you can read them all at once _BUT_ nft can accept limited amount of arguments (I don't recall the exact limit) so you may need to split it using some loop counter.